# How to target an element outside an iframe with different protocol using Javascript postMessage

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, postmessage

I have a button in an iframe and I wish that, it triggers another button, which is found outside the iframe, when clicked.

Here is a piece of code that I have been trying to work out.

The HTML

```
<body>
 <iframe id="layer-frame" src="https://somepage.com">
  <a href="https://page2.com" target="_blank" id="js-gopage2" class="js-iframepostmsg" alt="CLICK HERE TO Edit your profile">Edit your profile</a>
 </iframe>
 <div>
  <a class="close" href="#">Close<span></span></a>
 </div>
</body>
```

in Parent html

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event)
{
 if(event.data == "click!") {
  $('a.close').trigger('click');
 }
}
```

in iframe

```
var targetOrigin = window.location.host;
top.window.postMessage("click!", targetOrigin);
```

Comment: What value are you setting for `targetOrigin`? What does the JavaScript console say?

Comment: Hi, I forgot to add the origin link which is found in the variable "targetOrigin". Console shows nothing unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`targetOrigin = window.location.host` is going to give you the hostname of the page you are posting **from** but:

> `targetOrigin`
>   Specifies what the origin of `otherWindow` must be for the event to be dispatched

and

> the scheme, hostname, or port of otherWindow's document does not match that provided in `targetOrigin`

so you need to provide a complete origin (such as `http://example.com:234`), not just the hostname.

If you don't care which origin is allowed to read the message, use `"*"`.

Comment: Am understanding better the parameters here with your explanation. However, I have tried the "*" and since am on localhost, I tried "http://localhost:8090" as well and still nothing works. I think there might be something missing. Nothing appears in console and no error message from console as well